# stackView Inside UiscrollView contents are being shown bigger than the device screen size in simulator

Tags: uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios-autolayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RZDM.png)
contenst inside the UiView are tilted to both directions horizontally instead of fitting to the device' frame

Comment: maybe adjust your `UIWindow` bounds? it seems like your UIWindow is just bigger than the width of the screen, are you changing the size of `UIWindow` anywhere?

Comment: It looks like your Stack View probably has a Leading constraint of about 20? And it probably also has a Trailing constraint of about 20? If so, you also need to constrain it's Width equal to the scroll view width to -40 (***minus***) to make up for the 20-pts on each side.